# AngularJS and Play-Bootstrap: How to include a ng-click within @b3.submit?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, playframework, play-bootstrap

I'm using Scala-Play 2.5.10, Play-Bootstrap and AngularJS 1.x and I need one form submission to be handled from AngularJS. I then tried:

```
@b3.submit('class -> "btn btn-danger", 
           'ng-click -> "runInSampleSimulation()") { 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Run Simulation 
}
```

but the `ng-click` isn't recognized. I was hoping that it would be simply passed through into a Map as key-value pairs i.e. `<button type="@buttonType" @toHtmlArgs(innerArgsMap)>@text</button>` [see here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adrianhurt/play-bootstrap/523a5f1cf89b4257f8151dc66be1ab5642ac5c98/play24-bootstrap3/module/app/views/b3/buttonType.scala.html).

So I'd be left only with the choice of falling back to plan HTML like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="runInSampleSimulation()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Run Simulation
</button>
```

Is there a way to hook in the `ng-click` to the b3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to achieve this through changing the `form` instead of the `submit` button and using `ng-submit`.

Apparently there was no solution out-of-the-box. Although what I was hoping for was true that the Symbols are pass through, for some reason the dash `-` is an illegal Symbol for the templates. Therefore this would give an error:

```
@b3.form(routes.Simulation.computeInSample, 'ng-submit -> "runInSampleSimulation()") {
```

So I took the [form template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adrianhurt/play-bootstrap/master/play25-bootstrap3/module/app/views/b3/form.scala.html) and modified into a custom `b3/ngform.scala.html` like this:

```
@(action: Call, args: (Symbol, Any)*)(body: => Html)(implicit fc: b3.B3FieldConstructor)
<form method="@action.method" ng-submit="@bs.Args.get(args, 'ngsubmit)&#40;'@action.toString'&#41;"
      class="@fc.formClass @bs.Args.get(args, 'class)"
      @toHtmlArgs(bs.Args.remove(bs.Args.remove(bs.Args.inner(args, 'role -> "form"), 'ngsubmit), 'class).toMap)>
@body
</form>
```

Which I can then use like this:

```
@b3.ngform(routes.Simulation.computeInSample, 'ngsubmit -> "runInSampleSimulation") {
```

and generates exactly what I had wanted:

```
<form class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid" 
      role="form" method="GET" ng-submit="runInSampleSimulation('/simulation/in/')">
```